# Using Hoare-Rules to show PRECONDITION implies POSTCONDITION in a simple program (just 2 assignments)

Tags: proof, proof-of-correctness, hoare-logic

Using the Hoare-Rules I want to show that I can imply

```
{x >= 0} --> {a + y = x}
```

PROGRAMM

```
// PRECONDITION
{x >= 0}
a = x; 
y = 0;
// POSTCONDITION
{a + y = x}
```

Using the assignment rules I get

```
// PRECONDITION
{x >= 0}
{x + 0 = x}   // assignment rule
a = x; 
{a + 0 = x}   // assignment rule
y = 0;
// POSTCONDITION
{a + y = x}
```

To show

```
{x >= 0} --> {a + y = x}
```

therefore I need to show in a last step

```
{x >= 0} --> {x + 0 = x}
```

How can I show this or what is wrong in my proof?

Comment: content with my answer? if no, anything you want me to clarify? If yes, mind accepting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct.

To prove an implication formally, argue as follows:

1. Assume the antecedent, `x >= 0`
2. By [Additive identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_identity), we have `x + 0 = x`
3. By implication introduction (from 1 and 2) we have `x >= 0 --> x + 0 = x`